# Matching in list context does not return empty list. Why?

Tags: regex, perl

[from documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Matching-in-list-context)

> With or without parentheses, an empty list is returned upon failure.

But I do not get empty list upon failure:

```
my @l =  'a' !~ m/a/;
print scalar @l;       # 1
print defined $l[0];   # 1

use warnings;
print $l[0] eq '';     # 1
```

But with `=~` I get empty list:

```
my @l =  'a' =~ m/b/;
print scalar @l;       # 0
```

What I do not understand with `!~`?

`This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 3 (v5.30.3) built for x86_64-linux`

**UPD**

```perl
my $r =  { a => 'a', b => 'b', c => 'c' };
my $f =  { a => 'a', c => 'c' };

map{ $r->{ $_ } =~ $f->{ $_ } } %$f   or next; # If nothing is matched go to next record

map{ $r->{ $_ } !~ $f->{ $_ } } %$f   or next; # If all conditions meet, proceed
```

Comment: The doc says _Binary `"!~"` is just like `"=~"` except the return value is negated in the logical sense_. The behavior you are observing seems consistent with that.

Comment: @Dada: ((( This is inconsistent. So I can not write to check all matches: `map{ $d->$_ !~ $where->{ $_ } } keys %$where` like to check where all values does not match: `map{ $d->$_ =~ $where->{ $_ } } keys %$where`. Here I use map like reduce when it return empty list. So when we get empty list - we got the condition. How do you think, will we benefit if `!~` will return empty list?

Comment: What's $where and what's $d? Can you show a less abstract use case?

Comment: @choroba: in my case `$d` is `DBIx::Class::Result` row and `where` a hash where `key` is field name and `value` is regex to match. By matching I can decide to proceed row or not. `=~` nothing is matched, `!~` all is matched

Comment: I'd use `grep` or `any|none|all` from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List::Util).

Comment: Re "*This is inconsistent*", What did you expect? Return captured text when it doesn't match and nothing when it does match? Nothing is captured if there's no match, so that makes absolutely no sense. Of course it's inconsistent; it's impossible to be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the operand using `!~` can't cause the match operator to simply swap what it returns on a match and what it returns when there's no match.

In list context, the match operator normally returns the captured substrings, or an empty list if there's no match. Swapping the return values would require returning an empty list on a match, and the captured substrings when there's no match. That's impossible since nothing is captured when there's no match.

`s///` and `tr///` have similar problems as they normally return the number of substitutions.

Instead, `EXPR !~ OP` is short for `!( EXPR =~ OP )`, and `!` evaluates its operand in scalar context (since it's needs a true or false value).

---

```perl
# Go to next record if nothing matches.
grep { $r->{ $_ } =~ $f->{ $_ } } keys(%$f)
   or next;

# Go to next record if everything matches.
# (Go to next record if nothing doesn't match.)
grep { $r->{ $_ } !~ $f->{ $_ } } keys(%$f)
   or next;
```

Clearer:

```perl
use List::Util qw( all none );

# Go to next record if nothing matches.
none { $r->{ $_ } =~ $f->{ $_ } } keys(%$f)
   or next;

# Go to next record if everything matches.
all { $r->{ $_ } =~ $f->{ $_ } } keys(%$f)
   and next;
```